# WooCommerce hook for order creation from admin

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In my custom plugin (working in WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.x), I need to get the order ID when a new order is created. I tried different hooks but they work only when the customer creates an order and not when an order is created from admin.

I tried:

- woocommerce_new_order
- woocommerce_thankyou
- woocommerce_checkout_order_processed
- woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta

**Update**

Finally I used this:

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', function($order_id)
{
    if(!did_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed') 
        && get_post_type($order_id) == 'shop_order'
        && validate_order($order_id))
    {
         order_action($order_id);
    }
});
```

where *validate_order* is:

```
function validate_order($order_id)
{
    $order = new \WC_Order($order_id);
    $user_meta = get_user_meta($order->get_user_id());
    if($user_meta)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Thanks to *validate_order* the action isn't executed when you start to create the order. I use `!did_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed')` because I don't want that the action is executed if the order is created by a customer (I have a specific action for that, using `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`).

Comment: This should hopefully get it for you: `WC()->order->id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the admin page `.../wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order` to create the new order then there may not be a `WooCommerce` hook to do this as this order is created by the WordPress core.

However, the WordPress action `'save_post_shop_order'` will be called with the `$post_ID` which is the order id.

See function `wp_insert_post()` in `...\wp-includes\post.php`.

Comment: Thanks! The action `save_post_shop_order` is called when the order is created and every time the order is updated. It's almost good for me, but is there an action that it's called only when the order is created? (maybe `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}` in `...\wp-includes\post.php`, but `new_shop_order` doesn't work )

Comment: The action 'save_post_shop_order' has a boolean parameter $update which will be false on post creation.

Comment: Ok. The problem is that when you click on the button for create an order from admin, before you start to fill the order fields, the action `save_post_shop_order` is called. So I get an order ID of an empty order. In fact, if you exit from the order creation page, and you try to create a new order, the order ID is a new value. It would be better to use an action called only when the admin click on the button 'Save/add Order' and the order is shown in the order table.

Comment: Another problem, only in WooCommerce 3.x, using `save_post_shop_order` even when admin saves the order clicking on the button, the order is incomplete, without the customer data. Only when the admin saves the order a second time, the order is complete..

Comment: When using the admin page to make an order the order is done in steps. An empty order is first created and then that order may be updated multiple times. Each of these updates may have added or removed items. Further, an update may occur at a much later time in a different session. Also, an existing order in the order table may be further updated. I am not sure what you are trying to do but an action/filter later in order process may be more appropriate, i.e. when the order state changes to processing or completed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. I want to 'do something' when the admin clicks on the button that creates the order and the order is shown in order table. If the order isn't shown I don't want to do anything. I want to do the same thing when the admin reopens the order and clicks another time in the button that saves the changes he makes. I want to get all the data of the order when I have to 'do something', thus I don't want to get an empty order.

Comment: There may not be an action that is only triggered under the conditions you specified. However, you can always use a more generic action such as 'save_post_shop_order' and then check if the conditions you specified are true. In particular, I would look at the $_REQUEST variable to understand the 'nature' of the request.

Answer (score 5):

`woocommerce_new_order` hook is called after order creation:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {
    // ...
}, 10, 1);
```

Comment: This worked for me. WP 5.9.3, WC 5.6.2. Used like this `add_action('woocommerce_new_order', callback_function(), 10, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this hook `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` is is triggered when an order is manually created from the WordPress admin.