# WooCommerce 3.0: can't find hook which corresponds to an admin created backend order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Along the lines of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522910/woocommerce-hook-for-order-creation-from-admin), I am trying to connect to my own custom payment gateway when an admin creates an order via the admin panel using my payment gateway.

I have added the following code:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', array( $this, 'process_offline_order' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', array( $this, 'process_offline_order2' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_save_post_shop_order', array( $this, 'process_offline_order3' ) );
```

I have tried to drop in xdebug breakp points into those respective methods, but none of them are getting hit.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? what are you trying to do?

Comment: what exactly is your issue?

Comment: I'm trying to trigger an event which can connect to a payment gateway API when a WooCommerce admin creates an order on behalf of one of their customers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research and testing, I think that **the correct hook for that is** one of this WP hooks:

- [**`save_post_{$post->post_type}`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3499)
- [**`save_post`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3510)
- [**`wp_insert_post`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3521)

So I have used the first one  as it's the most convenient for "**`shop_order`**" post type:

```
add_action( 'save_post_shop_order', 'process_offline_order', 10, 3 );
function process_offline_order( $post_id, $post, $update ){

    // Orders in backend only
    if( ! is_admin() ) return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object (in a plugin)
    $order = new WC_Order( $post_id ); 

    // For testing purpose
    $trigger_status = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_hook_is_triggered', true );

    // 1. Fired the first time you hit create a new order (before saving it)
    if( ! $update )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hook_is_triggered', 'Create new order' ); // Testing

    if( $update ){
        // 2. Fired when saving a new order
        if( 'Create new order' == $trigger_status ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hook_is_triggered', 'Save the new order' ); // Testing
        }
        // 3. Fired when Updating an order
        else{
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hook_is_triggered', 'Update  order' ); // Testing
        }
    }
}
```

You will be able to test easily with this code. For me it's working fine.

---

I have also tried with **`woocommerce_before_order_object_save`** hook which have 2 arguments:

- **`$order`** (the WC_Order object )
- **`$data_store`** (The data to be stored through WC_Data_Store class)

**But I didn't get it working, as I was expecting.** I have found it in the source code of **`WC_Order`** [**`save()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#195-216) method.

Comment: This code all looks perfect, but I'm not able to get that method to trigger either locally or on my test server. I suppose it could be my configuration.