# Woocommerce add order from Admin Screen to AgileCRM

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to integrate woocommerce to AgileCRM. Reference to below question I think this plugin has the same problem, wherein the order details are updated in the CRM platform only when they come through the front-end checkout.

[WooCommerce hook for order creation from admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522910/woocommerce-hook-for-order-creation-from-admin)

My issue is I am not a plugin developer and the AgileCRM team say's we might have to write our own code for that. Shame they could do it in minutes where i have to dig every function and learn the plugin development.

I have found that as part of the plugin registration it has this in

funtions.php

```
function AgileWC_order_status_changed()
{
    global $AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS;
    $ordersArr = func_get_args();
    $wcorder = new WC_Order($ordersArr[0]);
    $order = AgileWC_getOrder($wcorder);

    $orderHook = AgileCRM::$hooks['order.updated'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['agileWCOrderHook'])) {
        $orderHook = $_SESSION['agileWCOrderHook'];
        unset($_SESSION['agileWCOrderHook']);
    }

    $agilecrm = new AgileCRM();
    $agilecrm->customerEmail = $wcorder->billing_email;
    $agilecrm->hook = $orderHook;
    $agilecrm->payLoad = array("order" => $order);
    $agilecrm->syncAsTags = "";

    if (isset($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS['sync_product_tags'])) {
        $agilecrm->syncAsTags .= "_products";
    }
    if (isset($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS['sync_category_tags'])) {
        $agilecrm->syncAsTags .= "_categories";
    }

    $agilecrm->post();
}
```

and in the plugin registration function, there is this code

```
if ($AGILEWC_DOMAIN && $AGILEWC_KEY) {
    if (is_array($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS)) {
        if (isset($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS['track_visitors']) || isset($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS['web_rules'])) {
            add_action('wp_footer', 'AgileWC_script');
        }

        if (isset($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS['sync_customers'])) {
            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'AgileWC_created_customer');
        }

        if (isset($AGILEWC_SYNC_OPTIONS['sync_orders'])) {
            add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'AgileWC_new_order');
            add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'AgileWC_order_status_changed');

           add_action('save_post_shop_order','AgileWC_order_status_changed');

            add_action('woocommerce_new_customer_note', 'AgileWC_new_customer_note');
        }
    }
}
```

**//Added by Me, but no action**
add_action('save_post_shop_order','AgileWC_order_status_changed');

Now I have read to some post that there is no woocommerce hook that I can use to call for the orders created by Admin.

Now my question is has anyone fixed this issue and if there is any help i can get to resolve this.

Thanks,
Gautam