# Hooks for order creation exclusively in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I need to detect when a new WooCommerce order is successfully created and set to ‘processing’—this is to add some extra functionality etc. This is fine to do on the frontend as it’s pretty easy to hook in when an order is created via either of the WooCommerce `woocommerce_thankyou` or `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hooks.

The problem I have is that **I also want this to work when creating a new order manually via the backend of the website**. I am using some custom fields when adding an order via manually which is used to manipulate the order when created. Unfortunately, although the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` does work for admin orders it seems to trigger before the order meta is saved—therefore when I try to retrieve any meta data it is empty.

To get round this, I have tried the suggestions on [WooCommerce hook for order creation from admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522910/woocommerce-hook-for-order-creation-from-admin) or on this [GitHub](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11967#issuecomment-249811534) thread which is to use the WordPress hooks `wp_insert_post` or `save_post_shop_order` (`save_post_{$post->post_type}`). This works to solve my order meta problem as it seems to trigger after the order meta is saved.

*However* — it triggers **everytime** there is an update or a new post so I need to find a way of detecting whether it’s a new post or not. There is an `$update` parameter on these hooks which is meant to show *‘Whether this is an existing post being updated or not’* but for some reason it always seems to be set to true even when it is a new post/order.

### To summarise:

- I need a WordPress/WooCommerce hook that is triggered after order/post meta is created via the backend *and* some way of only running this when an order is newly created and not updated.

The only other way potentially of doing this that I can think of is as per [this suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177670/63134) of checking post date vs. modified date but I just thought there must be a better way of doing this!

#### Here’s my current code just in case

```
function my_order_created ( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Don’t run if $post_id doesn’t exist OR post type is not order OR update is true
    if ( ! $post_id || get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'shop_order' || $update == 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    if ( $order && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ){

        // Do something

    }    

}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_order_created', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I have solved this before by checking for 'auto_draft' => 1 in the $_POST array. Seem like there would be a more elegant solution, but this did work in my case. I'm not posting as an answer in hopes someone with the better solution will do so.

Comment: @user3080408 — To be fair, I just tried it and it works the way I intended so thank you! We’ll see if anyone else adds an answer as I would have thought WordPress would have a more elegant way to do this but good job!

Comment: @Stuart Dis you tried `woocommerce_new_order` hook instead?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `woocommerce_new_order` hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {
     // your code
}, 10, 1);
```

Comment: In the latest Woo version 7.1.0 this has 2 variables:
```do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order->get_id(), $order );```

Answer (score 5):

*Update 2023*

Since WooCommerce 3 that has implemented [CRUD methods and data stores](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0), there are some **dedicated hooks**, that you can **specifically** use for **order creation**. :

You can use `woocommerce_new_order` **action hook** allowing you to trigger some custom code on order creation (located in the [`WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT` `create()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L93-L171) method).

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'action_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 2);
function action_woocommerce_new_order( $order_id, $order ) {
     // Here your custom action code
}
```

There is also `woocommerce_new_order_data` **filter hook** allowing you to **filter** some data inside the function `wp_insert_post()` before it's saved on order creation (located in the [`Abstract_WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT` `create()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L69-L107) method)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_order_data', 'action_woocommerce_new_order_data', 10, 2);
function action_woocommerce_new_order( $data_arr, $wp_error ) {
     // Here your custom code to filter data

     // Always return the main argument
     return $data_arr;
}
```

This is a much **better option** as it's just for **WooCommerce order creation**.