# How to set a transaction ID for manual payment methods like cash on delivery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a client offering free products and they want to bypass customers having to enter customer details but they rely on the transaction id to record orders from their QAD system connected via WooCommerce API.

My goal is to set a default transaction ID in the case that there is not one set from stripe or other payment methods. More specifically setting a transaction id to "FREESAMPLE" when someone checks out using Cash on Delivery.

This one is a little more complex and I didn't find anything on stack exchange for resolving this question.

I set up the payment method Cash on Delivery to only be available when the cart total is Zero dollars.

This worked, but Now they are not getting the order information in their QAD system due to not having the transaction ID.

I looked up the documentation for WooCommerce API about utilizing the transaction id field in orders and didn't find much in the way of setting a default option or an option for a payment method that doesn't generate a transaction ID from a third party payment gateway like Stripe.

Comment: I did find some code associated with creating an action when an order is set to processing here using:

    "'woocommerce_new_order'" - by Hamid Mohayeji


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094274/hooks-for-order-creation-exclusively-in-woocommerce-3

I just need to know how to add a transaction ID for that payment method at that point.

Comment: This is what I have come up with so far:

`<?php

//Set transaction id for cod...

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {

  if ( isset($available_gateways['cod']) ) {

    // set transaction id to 'FREESAMPLE'
  }

}, 10, 1);

?>`

I am getting the action for a new order and if cash on delivery is set do something.

Comment: I did find this information on setting the transaction id here thanks to WP KAMA:
https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Order::set_transaction_id

Comment: `<?php

//Set transaction id for cod...

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {

  if ( isset($available_gateways['cod']) ) {
    $value = 'FREESAMPLE' ;
    $WC_Order->set_transaction_id( $value );
  }

}, 10, 1);

?>`

Comment: So using some fundamental code from that example I may be able to use set_transaction_id :

`<?php

//Set transaction id for cod...

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {
  $available_gways = 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways';
  if ( isset($available_gways['cod']) ) {
    $value = 'FREESAMPLE' ;
    $WC_Order->set_transaction_id( $value );
  }

}, 10, 1);

?>`

Comment: I looked more into this and found the below article:
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: Cleaned up the code to be more specific utilizing the order object and now I am getting an error on checkout: "Order failed, please try again"

`//Set transaction id for cod...
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'transaction_generator', 10, 1); 
function transaction_generator($order_id, $order){
if($order->get_transaction_id() == 'cod'){
      $value = 'FREESAMPLE' ;
      $order->set_transaction_id($value);
    }
}`